# WebGL keep previous object

Tags: webgl

I'm learning webgl and trying to drop different objects from top of the canvas. Every time an object reaches the bottom a new object drops from the top.
This is working, but I wanna keep the object on the bottom. Every time a new obect drops from the dop the previous object disappears.
How can I solve this?

```
    function initWebGL() {
        canvas = document.getElementById("my-canvas");  
        gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL(canvas); 
        document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown, false);

            if(gl) {
                setupWebGL();
                initShaders();
                setupBuffers();
                getMatrixUniforms();

                 tick();

                }
                else{   
                    alert(  "Error: Your browser does not appear to support WebGL.");
                }




            function tick() {
            requestAnimFrame(tick);
            drawScene();
            animate();
            }

function setupBuffers() {


            l_VerticeBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, l_VerticeBuffer);

            var l_Vertices = 
                [-0.2 ,0.6,0.0,     
                -0.2,-0.6,0.0, 
                0.2 ,-0.6,0.0,  
                0.6 ,-0.6,0.0,
                0.6,-0.2,0.0,
                0.2,-0.2,0.0,
                0.2,0.6,0.0];

                l_VerticeBuffer.itemSize = 3;
                l_VerticeBuffer.numItems = 7;
                gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new  float32Array(l_Vertices), gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);


                L_IndexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();      
                gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, L_IndexBuffer);                  
                indices = [0,1,2,0,2,6,4,3,2,4,2,5,];
                gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
                }
function drawScene(){

            gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); //das sind die dinge die i in setupwebgl hab 
            gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
            gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

            mat4.perspective(45, canvas.width / canvas.height, 0.1, 100.0, pMatrix);
            mat4.identity(mvMatrix);

            mvPushMatrix();
            mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [move, up_down, -7.0]);
            mat4.rotateZ(mvMatrix, y_rot* Math.PI /40.0); 

            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, mirrorLVerticeBuffer); //passt
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(vertexPositionAttribute, mirrorLVerticeBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);//passt

            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, lColorBuffer);
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(vertexColorAttribute, lColorBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mirrorLIndexBuffer);

            setMatrixUniforms();

            gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indicesL.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT,0);

            mvPopMatrix();
```

}
var lastTime = 0;

```
function animate() {
    var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
    if (lastTime != 0) {
        var elapsed = timeNow - lastTime;

        if (up_down > GROUND_Y) {
        up_down -= (10 * elapsed) / 1000.0;
        }
    }
    lastTime = timeNow;
}
```

Comment: Its hard to tell from your description what is causing this behavior, can you link to your source code so we an understand why that's happening?

Comment: I think this happens because every time the object reaches the bottom I call initBuffers again. I think I have to do this in another way?

Comment: Yeah you probably shouldn't be calling initBuffers again. Though I am not sure, because I can't see your code. You should be calling gl.drawArrays() once for every object that is currently on the screen. So in the beginning when there is only 1 object you would only call it once per frame. But as more objects get dropped you will now be calling gl.drawArrays() more than once per frame depending on how many objects are on the screen.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm fairly new to WebGL. My Code is really long so I dont' know if I can post it here.
I'm trying this.

Comment: You can always try pasting the code, I've never hit a limit on Stackoverflow yet. Usually it will just add a scroll bar to the code.

Comment: ok I'm little bit confused about calling drawArrays depending on how many objects are on the screen. I've updated my post with code snippets.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say drawElements rather than drawArrays, because you are using drawElements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every L object you want to draw in the scene you'll need to have a different set of coordinates that says where that specific L object is. In your code you set the x position and y position of the L object with the `move` and `up_down` variables.

So create an array of objects where each element represents the coordinates of an L object:

```
var lObjects = [
    {
        move: 0,
        up_down: 3
    }
];
```

The above array has only one element (so one L shape) to begin with. Also I wasn't sure what your starting values for `move` and `up_down` were so I just gave them whatever value I wanted.

Now in your `drawScene()` loop through the `lObjects` and draw an L object for every element in `lObjects` (using the `move` and `up_down` values of each element).

```
function drawScene(){

    gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); //das sind die dinge die i in setupwebgl hab 
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    mat4.perspective(45, canvas.width / canvas.height, 0.1, 100.0, pMatrix);
    mat4.identity(mvMatrix);

    for(var i = 0; i < lObjects.length; i++) {
        mvPushMatrix();
        mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [lObjects[i].move, lObjects[i].up_down, -7.0]);
        mat4.rotateZ(mvMatrix, y_rot* Math.PI /40.0); 

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, mirrorLVerticeBuffer); //passt
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(vertexPositionAttribute, mirrorLVerticeBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);//passt

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, lColorBuffer);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(vertexColorAttribute, lColorBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mirrorLIndexBuffer);

        setMatrixUniforms();

        gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indicesL.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT,0);

        mvPopMatrix();
    }
}
```

Finally update your `animate()` to use the new `lObjects` array. Here is a modified version of your `animate()` that will only update the `up_down` of the newest L and whenever the newest L reaches the bottom it will add a new L to `lObjects` (so it will make an infinite amount of Ls).

```
function animate() {
    var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
    if (lastTime != 0) {
        var newestL = lObjects[lObjects.length - 1];
        var elapsed = timeNow - lastTime;

        if (newestL.up_down > GROUND_Y) {
            newestL.up_down -= (10 * elapsed) / 10000.0;
        } else {
            lObjects.push( { move: 0, up_down: 3 } );
        }
    }
    lastTime = timeNow;
}
```

Again watch out for the constants I used, you probably don't want to use them, but I wasn't sure what values you were using. I also slowed down the speed at which the Ls fell because it worked better with my constants.